# Generate auth token in login route and require it in other routes

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I am generating an auth token with the help of a separate serviceIn login from I am generating authentication token with help of some service.  I generate the token in the `login` route.  How can I prevent access to other routes until the login token is generated, and how can I access that token in the other routes?

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
  error=None
  if request.method=='POST':
    if request.form['username']!='admin' or request.form['password']!='1234':
      error ='Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
    else:          
      username=request.form['username']
      password=request.form['password']
      auth_url='http://192.168.206.133:5000/v2.0'
      token = generateToken(username=username, password=password, auth_url=auth_url)        
      return redirect(url_for('getstats'))
  return render_template('login.html', error=error)

# this route should require and use the auth token
@app.route('/metering')
def getstats():
    return render_template('metering.html')
```

Comment: add another `@` for login required.

Comment: `@app.route('/secret_page')
@login_required
def secret_page():
    pass` Here : http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/viewdecorators/

Comment: sorry  a lot friend. https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ But which db or style holding your user data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears that you are trying to access the token in different routes.

I suggest storing them in a session. To do so, make sure to import the `session` variable from `flask`: `from flask import session`.

You want to set the token's value in the `session.` Right now, I will use `auth_token` as the session field, but you can use anything you want:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
  error=None
  if request.method=='POST':
    if request.form['username']!='admin' or request.form['password']!='1234':
      error ='Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
    else:          
      username=request.form['username']
      password=request.form['password']
      auth_url='http://192.168.206.133:5000/v2.0'
      token = generateToken(username=username, password=password, auth_url=auth_url)
      session["auth_token"] = token # store the token in the session here
      session["authenticated"] = True
      return redirect(url_for('getstats'))
  return render_template('login.html', error=error)

from functools import wraps

def authenticated_resource(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        if session.get("authenticated"):
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    return decorated
```

Then, to access the token:

```
@app.route('/metering')
@authenticated_resource
def getstats():
    token = session.get("auth_token")
    # you might want to verify that the token was in the session, as such
    if token:
        return render_template('metering.html')
    else:
        abort(403)
```

Note: to use `abort`, you also need to import that from `flask`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, In the above code where we are sending and receiving token.......

Comment: @NeelabhSingh Oh, I see, I am editing my answer now on how to store the token.

Comment: thanks one more thing when I added `@authenticated_resource` it restrain to go `@app.route('/metering')` this is file but i need to redirect to login page. How I will do that. thanks...

Comment: @NeelabhSingh Sorry, I didn't see that you needed both. Check out my answer now.

Comment: sorry I got new problem `RuntimeError: the session is unavailable because no secret key was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.`

Comment: @NeelabhSingh You need to set a secret key in your Flask configuration: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/#builtin-configuration-values.

The secret key is essentially used to encrypt the session data. I'm not sure how you are configuring Flask but you should set it accordingly. I suggest using a randomized string (such as https://www.random.org/passwords/?num=1&len=24&format=html&rnd=new).

Comment: @RushyPanchal Thanks It will be very help, I upvote your answer. I will accept it ....